# Apache directory listing

Tags: apache-2.2, directoryindex

Hi i previously had setup a web server using apache 2.0.65, but i decided to update to 2.2. After updating i noticed that the look of the directory listing changed. It previously looked like [this](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/1-blog-pics/apache-crude-directory-listing.png), but now looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeMT5.png). How can i make it look like it did before updating?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

does this help enough? 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html

Also: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings
"For a more complete example, including a configuration for the icons displayed with the files, see conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf as distributed with Apache httpd."